# Pandas styler gradient vmin vmax from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visualization, pandas-styles

I have a dataframe df which looks like following.

```
  Parameter   M1   M2   M3  Relative Vmin  Relative Vmax
0        P1  1.5  3.1  3.0            1.0          100.0
1        P2  2.2  4.1  4.2            2.0            6.0
2        P3  3.2  3.5  3.4            2.5            6.5
```

I want to create a dataframe styler but instead of using the min/max of the axis, I would like to use the values in the Relative Vmin and Relative Vmax columns.

So in my example above, the Parameter P1 measurements are all "relatively" low with respect to those columns, even though M2 and M3 are higher than M1. I would like the styling to reflect this.

Is there any way to do this besides iterating through each row one-by-one?

Sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Parameter': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3'],
                        'M1': [1.5, 2.2, 3.2],
                        'M2': [3.1, 4.1, 3.5],
                        'M3': [3.0, 4.2, 3.4],
                        'Relative Vmin':[1,2,2.5],
                        'Relative Vmax':[100,6,6.5]})
measurements = ['M1', 'M2', 'M3']
df.style.background_gradient(axis=1, subset=measurements)
# ^ I don't want this, I want to do something like vmin=df['Relative Vmin'], vmax=df['Relative Vmax']
```

Comment: For more complicated mappings you can use the `gmap` argument for determining the colors. The gradient map provides a numeric overlay that allows you to specifically state what color each cell should be, whilst displaying the real value of that cell. You can use standard pandas DataFrame apply and map functions to create your `gmap` using any complex mathematical functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex color mapping you should use `gmap` and calculate the colour map yourself.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "M1": [1.5, 2.2, 3.2],
    "M2": [3.1, 4.1, 3.5],
    "M3": [3.0, 4.2, 3.4],
    "Vmin": [1.0, 2.0, 2.5],
    "Vmax": [100.0, 6.0, 6.5]
})
df["M1_gmap"] = (df["M1"] - df["Vmin"]) / (df["Vmax"] - df["Vmin"])
df["M2_gmap"] = (df["M2"] - df["Vmin"]) / (df["Vmax"] - df["Vmin"])
df["M3_gmap"] = (df["M3"] - df["Vmin"]) / (df["Vmax"] - df["Vmin"])
df.style.background_gradient(subset=["M1", "M2", "M3"], axis=None, gmap=df[["M1_gmap", "M2_gmap", "M3_gmap"]].values)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a [Rescaling (*min-max normalization*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Rescaling_(min-max_normalization)) and use it as a `gmap` :

```
meas = df[measurements].to_numpy()
vmin = df["Relative Vmin"].to_numpy()
vmax = df["Relative Vmax"].to_numpy()

rescaling = (meas - vmin[:, None]) / (vmax-vmin)[:, None]

df.style.background_gradient(axis=None, subset=measurements, gmap=rescaling)
```

[image]

[<sup>*Old answer*</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12156dcf-1d83-4d30-9e02-6bd78b687961/view-source)

Comment: Yes this works, but it is slow. On my dataframe it takes 120 seconds to run (versus about 15 seconds to just run the background_gradient without any loop or vmin/vmax).

Another idea I was thinking would be to normalize all the values into a duplicate dataframe, then apply the background_gradient, then copy the resulting formats to apply to the original dataframe.

Comment: I updated my answer with another approach that may give you some insights.

Comment: In your updated response, tmp.export() doesn't export the actual css (it exports the rules which then get re-applied back to the original df). The result ends up the same as just applying background_gradient to the original df with no vmin or vmax.

Comment: I'm resurrecting an old one but I updated my answer to use a vectorial approach.